# Installing Kaspersky Endpoint Security for Linux fails

Tags: antivirus, keys

I have Linux Ubuntu 12.04 & tried to install Kaspersky Endpoint Security 8 for Linux. I choose the trial version link, give my email address & receive an email with further download links.
After clicking on the trial version, I got a link to a .deb package & to a .zip file containing trial keys (trial-keys-kaspersky.zip). According to the email from Kaspersky, this .zip file contains the activation code, but when I unzip it, I can see a lot of .txt files.

However, I run the .deb with **sudo dpkg -i kes4wlks_8.0.1-50_i386.deb** . Later, the installation demands to run **sudo perl /opt/kaspersky/kes4lwks/bin/kes4lwks-setup.pl**
I answers all questions of this perl file but then it asks to enter the path to the key file with the extension .key.

**And that is the problem !** In the trial-keys-kaspersky.zip file (mentioned above) there is **NO** file with that extension. As result, the GUI of Kaspersky says that no license is installed.

I did not understand it why Kaspersky makes it so difficult. Please, can somebody give a step-by-step help how to install it ?

EDIT: a list of the file in the .zip file:

- KSOS 5+1 - Exp.Date 31.12.2016.txt
- Data Leak Protection f. Collaboration-Exp. Date 31.12.2016.txt
- KSV Desktop - Exp. Date 31.12.2016.txt
- Systems Management - Exp. Date 31.12.2016.txt
- Total Sec. f. Business - Exp. Date 31.12.2016.txt
- KES Advanced - Exp. Date 31.12.2016.txt
- KES Select - Exp. Date 31.12.2016.txt
- Data Leak Protection f. Mail Server - Exp. Date 31.12.2016.txt
- Sec. f. Collaboration - Exp. Date 31.12.2016.txt
- Sec.f. File Server - Exp. Date 31.12.2016.txt
- Sec. f. Internet Gateway - Exp. Date 31.12.2016.txt
- Sec. f. Mail Server - Exp. Date 31.12.2016.txt
- Sec. f. Mobile Server - Exp. Date 31.12.2016.txt
- KSV Core - Sec. f. Mail Server - Exp. Date 31.12.2016.txt
- KSV Server - Sec. f. Mail Server - Exp. Date 31.12.2016.txt

Comment: Try changing the extensions of the two KES files to .key.

Comment: Nope, it does not work. It says:  "None of the key files is correct for this application." And it tells that the signature of the license(s) is invalid. But I got them via email after entering my address. They must be valid.

Comment: Did you download Select, Advanced or Total?

Comment: I'm also not sure where you get this ZIP. I signed up for the trial and was presented with a product key to copy.

Comment: @Zacharee1 : Ok, then can you describe or give the links which you use?

Comment: http://usa.kaspersky.com/business-security/free-trials/endpoint-select

Comment: @Zacharee1: I ve chosen the Endpoint Security for Business version since there was a link to the linux version

Comment: That _is_ KES Business. It's KES Business Select. You haven't clarified on whether you downloaded Select, Advanced or Total, and you haven't given a source for what you downloaded.

Comment: Ok, now I did the same what you did. I also signed up for trial and got an activation code via email. Then I downloaded the .deb package for KES Business Select. But during installation, it asks me to enter the path to the .key file which I do not have.

Comment: paste the text into a file with the .key extension.

Comment: Ok, bu then I get the message: "The license from /home/pac/Downloads/code.key" could not be installed: signature of license key is invalid.

Comment: You're going to have to contact Kaspersky about this then.